# Determine the type of an array which stores the pointer to other arrays of different dimensions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

I have many constant 2D arrays of all possible permutation of integer in [0,LEN) for many LEN:

```c
static const char permu2[][2] = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
static const char permu3[][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2},
                                {1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}};
static const char permu4[][4] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 2}, {0, 2, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 1}, {0, 3, 1, 2},
    {0, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 0, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 0},
    {1, 3, 0, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 3}, {2, 0, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 0, 3},
    {2, 1, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 2}, {3, 0, 2, 1},
    {3, 1, 0, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 0, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 0}};
static const char permu5[][5] = {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 2, 4}, /*... */}
// and many more as you can imagine...
```

And I'd like to store the pointers to those arrays in another array:

```c
static const char *permu[] = {0,      0,      permu2, permu3, permu4,
                             permu5, permu6, permu7, permu8};
static const int fac_seq[] = {1,   1,    2,     6,      24,      120,
                              720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800};
```

So that for a given LEN=n, I can access those constants in this way:

```c
const int n = 8;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < fac_seq[n]; i++ ) {
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
        printf( "%2d", *( permu[n] + n*i  + j ) );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Although this will compile and work correctly, the compiler (gcc) complains like:

```
30.c:1966:47: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 static const char *permu[] = {0,      0,      permu2, permu3, permu4,
                                               ^~~~~~
30.c:1966:47: note: (near initialization for ‘permu[2]’)
30.c:1966:55: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 static const char *permu[] = {0,      0,      permu2, permu3, permu4,
                                                       ^~~~~~
30.c:1966:55: note: (near initialization for ‘permu[3]’)
```

What should be the right type for the `permu` array? I tried `const char **permu[]` and still got the same warnings.

Comment: You could try `static const void *permu[]`? You would then have to cast it when accessed. Alternatively you can make each array one-dimensional and work out the indexing yourself.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, that works, thanks! Just make it an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
static const void *permu[] = { };
```

You would then have to cast it when accessed.

Alternatively you can make each array one-dimensional and work out the indexing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The correct declaration is

```
static const char (*permu[9])[] = {0,      0,      permu2, permu3, permu4,
                                   permu5, permu6, permu7, permu8};
```

`permu` is an array of 9 pointers to arrays of unknown numbers of `const char`s. Writing the `9` is optional; it can be inferred from the initializer. You *could* instead make it an array of pointers to `void`, as in the other answer, but it's best to preserve as much information as possible. You use it like this:

```
const int n = 4;
const char (*perms)[n] = permu[n];
for (size_t i = 0; i < fac_seq[n]; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%2d", perms[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Note that I perform a cast with the assignment to `perms`. I take a pointer to an array of unknown size and convert it to a pointer where the array size is actually `n`. This is what allows the double `[]` syntax later: the type `const char[n]` has a defined size (`sizeof(char)*n`), so we know how far we need to skip for `perms[i]`.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_Ffgi7)

Comment: I'm somewhat reluctant to the VLA in C. Do you think it will slow down the program? (cuz the factorial sequence blows up really fast)

Comment: Wait, this is not VLA right? It's just a type cast and no real allocation is done on stack ... I'm right?

Comment: It is a VLA type because it is a pointer to an array where the size is a variable. No, it's not slow because there is no stack allocation.